# Cannot connect to database of hosted server

Tags: mysql, godaddy

I have been trying to connect PowerBi desktop to the MySQL database of my site hosted on godaddy.com but I have not been able to and I keep getting the following error,

"MySQL: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

I have installed mysql-connector-net-6.6.5.msi and I am able to connect to my localhost, but not my website.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to get a more specific error message from your client software.

Comment: This is all I get though, no error code or anything.

Comment: Use the mysql commandline tool to see if it can connect.  If not, it will provide a better error message.